# Enlarge image on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, animation, hover

```
<ul>
    <li><img /></li>
    <li><img /></li>
    <li><img /></li>
    <li><img /></li>
    <li><img /></li>
</ul>
```

Its a horizontal list, not vertical.

**How can we enlarge one of the images, when we hover on it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do something like this by maintaing two images.

we did some example , please change the names accordingly

```
$('.itemBox').bind('mouseenter',function(){
            $lrgImage = $(this).find('img');
            lrgImageSrc = $lrgImage.attr('src');
            bkImage = 'url(' + lrgImageSrc + ')';
            $(this).css('background-image',bkImage);
            $(this).css('background-position','center center');
            $lrgImage.fadeOut('fast');

        });
        $('.itemBox').bind('mouseleave',function(){
            $lrgImage = $(this).find('img');
            $(this).css('background-image','none');
            $lrgImage.fadeIn('fast');

        });
```

This solution will take care of image getting blur on increasing height and width

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/pfuWr/

```
ul img:hover {
    width: 180px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

You'll need a workaround to support IE6.

---

For IE6, you could try wrapping the image in an `<a>`, and doing this:

```
ul a:hover > img{
    width: 180px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: This solution will have image blur issues. we need to swap the image with high resolution image , otherwise images looks bad

Comment: @gov - Depends. You could have one higher resolution image, have CSS make it smaller by default, then bring it to its natural size with the `:hover`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do this in jquery:

```
$('li > img').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css('width', '250px');
    $(this).css('height', '250px');
})
$('li > img').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css('width', '200px');
    $(this).css('height', '200px');
})
```

This will tear the design quite a bit though - you might wanna look into taking the same picture and overlaying it over the image on a different z-index. Or you can [clone](http://docs.jquery.com/Clone) the image, place it in the middle with [UI position](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/) and use .attr() or .css() to change it's size.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easily with CSS transform property.
The scale function can be used to enlarge and reduce the size of an element.
It technically applies a 3d transformation.
The default scale of all elements is 1.
In order to increase the size of the image on hover,
you can do:

```
.ul img:hover {
   transform : scale(1.2); 
   transition : 0.5s ease; //Some animation
}
```

For further reading on transform, you can [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale())